# Simple pdf report with parameters and JasperReport doesn't work

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm trying to do a simple report with JasperReport, so I designed the jrxml with Jaspersoft studio and write this code to pass the parameters and generate the pdf:

```
            JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("path.jrxml");

            HashMap<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
            parameters.put("name", "name");
            parameters.put("lastname", "lastname");

            JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, new JREmptyDataSource());

            JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jp, "path_to.pdf");
```

But when I run the application I get the error : `java: cannot access java.sql.Connection class file for java.sql.Connection not found`
But I don't want to use sql connections for a simple report. I tried to remove "JREmptyDataSource()" from the code but I get as output an empty pdf.

Anyone has some ideas on how to fix this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should post the full stack trace

Comment: @AlexK it's only "java: cannot access java.sql.Connection class file for java.sql.Connection not found"

Comment: Did you try to debug? Which line of code cause this error?