# Getting "cannot access java.sql.Connection" on running report via Java code

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am trying to create an application that prints a report to the user in PDF using jasper report and Intellij Idea but my program is returning this error:

```
C:\Users\USER\IdeaProjects\Concrete Mix Design\src\main\java\com\example\concrete_mix_design\Controllers\MainController.java:1031:50
java: cannot access java.sql.Connection
  class file for java.sql.Connection not found
```

I have included the Jasper report maven dependency to my pom.xml file. Here is my code

```
public void printReport(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws FileNotFoundException, JRException, URISyntaxException {
    JasperReport jasperReport=getJasperReport();

    Map<String,Object> parameters =getParameters();

    JRDataSource datasource=new JREmptyDataSource();

    JasperPrint jasperPrint=JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport,parameters,datasource);

    JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint);
}

private Map<String, Object> getParameters() {
    Map<String,Object> parameters=new HashMap<>();
    return parameters;
}

private JasperReport getJasperReport() throws JRException {
    InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/JasperReport.jrxml");

    JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(inputStream);
    return jasperReport;
}
```

Comment: Duplicates: [Simple pdf report with parameters and JasperReport doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71431671/876298)

Comment: i have not seen a solution in the related post.

Comment: what more can i provide? Thanks in advance

Comment: What version of jdk are you using?

Comment: jdk Version 20.0.2